# Subtract multiple cells if between date with Excel

Tags: countif

Trying to subtract three cells (N1-P1-T1) when cell K1 is between two dates (">="&U2 and "<="&V2).

I can't seem to figure out how to subtract three cells when the date is between two dates.

Data is on COMPLETE sheet in Collums N, P, and T. This formula will be on STATS sheet with the date ranges at U2 and V2.

Here is my AVERAGEIFS formula that works:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(COMPLETE!$Q:$Q,COMPLETE!$K:$K,">="&$U2,COMPLETE!$K:$K,"<="&$V2)
```